# Changing the order of 3D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume a 3D array `g` where it is denoted by `g[i,j,t]`. Now, I want to change the order of the arrays so it would have a structure as `g[t,i,j]`. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: `A = np.full((4,3,2), 0)` can be transposed as you wish by `B = np.transpose(A,(2,0,1))`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by permutation through `np.transpose`.

```
>>> x = np.ones((1, 2, 3))
>>> np.transpose(x, (2, 0, 1)).shape
```

The output is

```
(3, 1, 2)
```